# Boost bind and 'result_type': is not a member, c++03-friendly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++03, c++20, boost-bind

The latest 16.6 update to Visual Studio 2019 removed `std::plus::result_type`, `std::minus::result_type`, and related typedefs. (They're deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.) A greatly simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
template <typename FF>
struct function_wrapper {
    function_wrapper(FF func, const std::string& name) : func_(func), name_(name) { }
    int operator()(int i1, int i2) const { return func_(i1, i2); }
    // ... other stuff ...
    FF func_;
    std::string name_;
};

template <typename FF>
int use_function(const function_wrapper<FF>& func, const std::pair<int, int>& args) {
    return func(args.first, args.second);
}

funcWrapper<boost::function<int(int, int)>> plus_func(std::plus<int>(), "plus");
std::cout << use_function(plus_func, std::make_pair<int, int>(1, 2)) << std::endl;
```

After the update, this no longer compiles, generating the error:

```
boost\1.72.0\boost\bind\bind.hpp(75,25): error C2039: 'result_type': is not a member of 'std::plus<int>'
```

I can't add a `result_type` typedef back into `std::plus`, so I need another way to fix this. The thing is, the resulting code needs to compile under C++03, too, so lambdas and >=C++11 constructs are not a viable option. I can re-implement `std::plus` and add in the now-removed typedefs myself to make Boost happy, but is there a better way?

Comment: Note: `std::make_pair` is supposed to be invoked without explicit template arguments, i.e., `std::make_pair(1, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap old functors with:

```
template <typename F>
struct functor;

template <template <typename> class F, typename T>
struct functor<F<T> > : F<T>
{
    typedef T result_type;
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef T second_argument_type;
};
```

Then:

```
function_wrapper<boost::function<int(int, int)> >
     plus_func(functor<std::plus<int> >(), "plus");
//             ~~~~~~~^              ~^~
```

---

Alternatively, you can call `boost::bind` specifying the result type as a template argument:

```
boost::bind<int>(func, args...);
```

or:

```
boost::bind(boost::type<int>(), func, args...);
```